# AngularJS Pagination Directive w/ Isolate Scope

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-directive

I have the following pagination directive written by a member of my team:

```
myApp.directive('pagination', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $rootScope) {
            var halfDisplayed = 1.5,
                    displayedPages = 3,
                    edges = 2;
            $scope.getInterval = function() {
                return {
                    start: Math.ceil($scope.currentPage > halfDisplayed ? Math.max(Math.min($scope.currentPage - halfDisplayed, ($scope.pages - displayedPages)), 0) : 0),
                    end: Math.ceil($scope.currentPage > halfDisplayed ? Math.min($scope.currentPage + halfDisplayed, $scope.pages) : Math.min(displayedPages, $scope.pages))
                };
            };
            $scope.selectPage = function(pageIndex) {
                $scope.currentPage = pageIndex;
                $scope.$apply();
                $scope.draw();
                $scope.paginationUpdate();
            };
            $scope.appendItem = function(pageIndex, opts) {
                var options, link;

                pageIndex = pageIndex < 0 ? 0 : (pageIndex < $scope.pages ? pageIndex : $scope.pages - 1);

                options = $.extend({
                    text: pageIndex + 1,
                    classes: ''
                }, opts || {});

                if (pageIndex === $scope.currentPage) {
                    link = $('<span class="current">' + (options.text) + '</span>');
                } else {
                    link = $('<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-link">' + (options.text) + '</a>');
                    link.bind('click', function() {
                        $scope.selectPage(pageIndex);
                    });
                }

                if (options.classes) {
                    link.addClass(options.classes);
                }

                $element.append(link);
            };
            $rootScope.draw = function() {
                $($element).empty();
                var interval = $scope.getInterval(),
                        i;

                // Generate Prev link
                if (true) {
                    $scope.appendItem($scope.currentPage - 1, {
                        text: 'Prev',
                        classes: 'prev'
                    });
                }

                // Generate start edges
                if (interval.start > 0 && edges > 0) {
                    var end = Math.min(edges, interval.start);
                    for (i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                        $scope.appendItem(i);
                    }
                    if (edges < interval.start) {
                        $element.append('<span class="ellipse">...</span>');
                    }
                }

                // Generate interval links
                for (i = interval.start; i < interval.end; i++) {
                    $scope.appendItem(i);
                }

                // Generate end edges
                if (interval.end < $scope.pages && edges > 0) {
                    if ($scope.pages - edges > interval.end) {
                        $element.append('<span class="ellipse">...</span>');
                    }
                    var begin = Math.max($scope.pages - edges, interval.end);
                    for (i = begin; i < $scope.pages; i++) {
                        $scope.appendItem(i);
                    }
                }

                // Generate Next link
                if (true) {
                    $scope.appendItem($scope.currentPage + 1, {
                        text: 'Next',
                        classes: 'next'
                    });
                }
            };
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            $timeout(function() {
                scope.draw();
            }, 2000);
            scope.$watch(scope.paginatePages, function() {
                scope.draw();
            });
        },
        template: '<div class="pagination-holder dark-theme">' + '</div>',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

Unfortunately, when he wrote it, the directive refered to controller variables and functions:

```
function PatientListModalConfigCtrl($scope, $rootScope, myService) {
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.paginationUpdate = function() {
        var list = myService.search($scope.currentPage + 1);
        list.then(function(data) {
            $rootScope.List = data[1];
            $rootScope.pages = data[0];
        });
    };
};
```

I was able to replace the function call with `$scope[]();` using the attr parameter, but as soon as I try to add:

```
scope: {
    currentPage: '=',
    totalPages: '='
}
```

into the directive and isolate the directive from the controller, the pagination stops displaying altogether.  Can I use the attr parameter for these two variables as well?  I would prefer to use the scope in the directive because the variables will be changing, but my attempts have failed.  I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Do you adjust the directive in the HTML to pass values to the scopes as well?

Comment: Yes, I used the following with the scope declared in the directive but it still failed.    `<div pagination="paginationUpdate();" current-page="currentPage" total-pages="pages" style="float: right;"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have to say the whole directive looks a bit poorly designed. The dependancy on $rootScope is a big code smell, so is all the injecting of HTML in the controller.

To get on topic, you are two-way binding to primitives (integers). I am not entirely sure that's your entire problem, but it won't work as you expect. It's very logical once you think about it, how could AngularJS ever put any data back into (i.e update) a primitive?

By the look of it, you don't actually want *two-way* binding, you just need to send in some values. For such simple data you can define them as attributes ('@'), and then use attrs.$observe() to listen to the changes. As for the HTML, you can then use `current-page="{{currentPage}}"` to pass in the value (please note, it will be as a string, which you can then parse back).

Another option could be to pass in an object (using two-way binding). Example:

```
page = {
    currentPage: 3,
    totalPages: 14
}
```

Comment: I agree, I really don't like that the team lead chose to use $rootScope as much as he did.  Passing an object didn't work, but passing values and attrs.$observe() worked to get the pagination to display and function.  Do you have any suggestions on how to update the current page outside of the directive, though?  The $scope.selectPage function originally set the value in the controller and my service needs this value to update in order to work.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by updating current page outside of directive, but then I haven't really studied the code that well, and all the HTML littered all over the place makes it hard. That said, directives shouldn't work outwards, they only work inwards so to speak. So you define a template, and the directive has responsibilty for that template only. You can add to it or remove things from it, but outside should be off limits. So you need to define the directive at a high enough level for it to emcompass everything. It's hard to give a good suggestion without the requirements.

Comment: I got it to work by placing an $emit in the directive and a $on listener in the controller.  I don't think it is necessarily an ideal solution, but given how bad the original directive was, I am happy that the directive is now as reusable as it is.